# Closed questions must not be deletable before they are reopened for X duration

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, vote-to-delete

There is an intrinsic flaw in the SO, whereby closed questions are subject to being deleted because the available answers are of poor quality.

Suggestion:

Question cannot be subject to being deleted after it has been closed. Instead, the answer should be first re-opened for at least 7 days before it can be deleted. This would allow enough time for community to suggest alternative answers and prevent people from deleting the question simply because the answers are bad.

Case example:

The case that I will use as an example is the following question: [PDO support for multiple queries (PDO_MYSQL, PDO_MYSQLND)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd).

I have suggested re-opening the question in SO chat because the question itself is valid (it covers a use case of PDO that's not articulated in the documentation) and the answer to the question is of poor quality. Furthermore, the question has received a significant number of views, meaning that there was a number of people researching the issue, some of which might have suggested better solutions.

However, instead the question has been suggested to be deleted because "the answer that was given is completely retarded and actively harmful".

```
10:19 AM Gajus Kuizinas
I don't believe this should be closed with the up to date SOF rules? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd
 
10:22 AM tereško
you know why it was closed, @GajusKuizinas ?! Because the answer that was given is completely retarded and actively harmful
  
10:23 AM Gajus Kuizinas
@tereško Sure, now we know it. This is not clear (was not clear) from anywhere in the docs at the time.

10:23 AM Second Rikudo
@tereško Oh, to preform multiple queries.
 
10:23 AM Gajus Kuizinas
This can be demonstrated from the number of views.
 
10:23 AM tereško
@GajusKuizinas which would make it a good reason for deletion because it spreads BAD CODE
 
10:26 AM Second Rikudo
@GajusKuizinas The answer is crap. Having more views only makes it worse.
  
10:52 AM Gajus Kuizinas
You are suggesting to delete a closed question because the answer is not great. That makes a lot of sense.
 
10:53 AM Second Rikudo Second Rikudo
@GajusKuizinas We are suggesting to delete a closed questions because the only answer spread bad and harmful code. Yes.
 
10:53 AM Gajus Kuizinas
@SecondRikudo Because no one can leave another answer. The question is closed.
 
10:55 AM Second Rikudo
@GajusKuizinas There really isn't a very useful answer to this question. What do you want us to tell you? "You shouldn't have two queries at the same time" anyway?
 
10:57 AM Gajus Kuizinas
@SecondRikudo You are not in position to tell what PDO should or should not allow. Restricting access to a resource describing PDO behaviour is not going to alter what PDO can do. Instead, you should focus on meaningful answer suggesting the solution and warning about dangers.
 
10:59 AM Second Rikudo
The fact that you can do something doesn't mean you should do it. Multiple SQL statements is most certainly and completely objectively, a bad practice. Regardless of how you try to use it.
The fact that the answer simply tells you "Oh, just don't use prepared statements or use emulated prepared statements" doesn't really help your case here.
Don't get us wrong, deletion is a tool to prevent the spread of crap, which, in this case, is the crappy answer.
We cannot delete the answer because it's not negatively voted, and the question doesn't offer much salvageable merit too. So we decided to vote to delete it.
You can go to Meta Stack Overflow and present your case there, but I doubt you'll make much of a difference.
```

[Full transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15966056#15966056).

In this particular case, the question covers a feature of the http://php.net/pdo that is there by design. Risk assessment should be left to the individual developers and not to a group of members from an arbitrary (nonetheless, influential) community.

Comment: So to delete a question, you need to reopen it and leave it open for X days?

Comment: That's the suggestion.

Comment: Have you stopped to consider that maybe questions are deleted because the question is bad or off-topic, and they have nothing to do with any answers?

Comment: @psubsee2003 That's fine, but the example that I have presented is clearly not the case.

Comment: I won't speak to this specific post, but in general, you'd be blocking far mor garbage from getting deleted that you would be saving from deletion.

Comment: If the community deems the question worthy of answering it will be reopened... it's sat on 4 reopen votes right now so you might just get your wish. I don't see how this feature request is at all logical, reopen votes already solve this problem for questions worthy of reopening, it doesn't make sense for terrible questions to be given a free 7 days open window before deletion.

Comment: @OGHaza I agree that your arguments are correct when looking at the issue from the bad question perspective. I should have concentrated on the re-open feature. **Maybe, there should be a feature that allows to suggest an answer to a closed question? That depending on the number of votes is either allowed or not**.

Comment: Why don't you PHPholes (yeah, I like that, gonna keep it) just fix the answer?  Or is it impossible to do using best practices?

Comment: Best practices are subjective.. I have explained why there is nothing wrong with the existing answer in the comment, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd#comment35480395_6461110.

Comment: fyi, question is now open.

Comment: and if your 7 day rule had been in effect, nothing would have happened for 7 days and the question would have been deleted... If that answer is pure garbage then getting the question opened has just made the advice look more legit

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I disagree with your [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Asking to require a question to be closed, reopened (for 7 days), *then* deleted makes no sense.

Currently the system requires a question to be closed *before* it can be deleted. Anyone < 20k has to wait 2 days before they can vote-to-delete. This is *good* as it gives time between a question being closed and deleted to enable it to be reopened, and adds a barrier to prevent the question being deleted immediately.

**Normally** the close, delete process starts because the *question* is crap, not the answers. In this case (the majority of cases), you could leave a question open for a day, month, or year and the question will still be unsalvageable by the community.

---

In *this particular instance*, I'm not sure where the idea that questions-with-bad-answers-have-to-be-deleted came from. The reason given for closing that question is incorrect. Re-opening and adding new answers is what should happen here, and I've voted-to-reopen as such.

Answer (score 7):

This is the suggested feature:

> Question cannot be subject to being deleted after it has been closed. Instead, the answer should be first re-opened for at least 7 days before it can be deleted. This would allow enough time for community to suggest alternative answers and prevent people from deleting the question simply because the answers are bad.

(I presume it should read "[...] the *question* should be first re-opened [...]".)

**There is no need for this feature request because there *already* is a path away from deletion and towards reopening.** This path is to edit the question to remove the problems that were in it. Or if a question was erroneously closed, the solution is to raise awareness on Meta or in chat. The community can overturn the decisions of the community.

**The requested feature is harmful.** The suggestion here seems to be based on the incorrect assumption that questions are *generally* closed because they have bad answers. This is not the case at all. The vast majority of questions that are closed are closed because the *question* is not a good fit for SO. For instance, all the questions that ask for off site resources ("Is there a tool...", "What framework can I use for..."). These questions are *intrinsically* not a good fit for SO. There's no debate to be had in these cases. The question is just bad and should be deleted. In cases where the question is salvageable, then see above.

The problem with the feature request is that the vast majority of questions which are closed would then benefit from *undeserved* reopening. This would effectively nullify the entire closing mechanism.

We often get suggestions on Meta where to fix a rare problem a feature is suggested which have for consequence to create *bigger problems* elsewhere. This feature request here seems to be one such case.

**So this feature request should be rejected.**

I'm not going to address whether the specific question mentioned in the question here should be reopened or deleted because I don't know enough about that specific technology.

Answer (score 6):

> There is an intrinsic flaw in the SO, whereby closed questions are subject to being deleted because the available answers are of poor quality.

Generally speaking, closed questions are subject to deletion because the question itself it bad.  This has absolutely nothing to do with the quality of the answers.

Deletion is a necessity to help keep the site clean.  There are too many ridiculously bad questions or completely off-topic questions asked that have no business being on the site.  There's nothing to gain by reopening the question at all, let alone leaving it open for any amount of time, just so the community can do its own house keeping.

Comment: I see your argument. It makes sense in case the reason for closing the question is poor quality of the question itself. Though, there should be means to moderate a closed question answers.. I know you can delete answer if it has negative vote. In the example case, the answer has 44 upvotes. Which would make it look that closing the question because the answer is poor does not make sense.

Comment: Maybe vote to delete answer would be more approriate? But even then, if community thinks the answer is good (44 upvotes), this does not make sense.. the real evil here is that closed question does not allow new answers, and maybe in this particular case, we should question whether question was closed by mistake.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas 20K users can delete answers that are downvoted.  Mods can delete any answer.  However, for cases like this, deletion is not appropriate because mods should nt be in a position to make technical judgement on answers.  Downvoting is the solution in these cases.  Unfortunately it will take a lot of downvoting to correct this answer

Answer (score 4):

Everything you need already exists

> I have suggested re-opening the question in SO chat because the question itself is valid

Feature #1 - Voting to reopen

> the answer to the question is of poor quality

Feature #2 - The downvote button

> instead the question has been suggested to be deleted

Feature #3 - The flag link - if you believe a question has been closed for an invalid reason, flag it to a moderator